# Fast forward timer

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm having trouble with fast forwarding a timer. It is very basic at this stadium. I have a interval that add numbers. Like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    //+1 second
    //Format output to 00:00
    //Handle minute update
}, 1000);
```

This works perfect. The timer is going at normal speed. What I want to do is fast forwarding this timer. I want a timer minute to take 1 real second. I have tried:

```
setInterval(function () {
    //+1 second
    //Format output to 00:00
    //Handle minute update
}, 15);
```

That works sometimes and sometimes not. Sometimes it stops att 01:02 instead of 01:00. It may be my lack of math knowledge but I don't know. How would you do it? I am going to stop and start the timer every "timer minute" so it's important that the interval is correct.

**EDIT**
Here is a fiddle of how I want it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/pF4gs/

**EDIT 2**
Maybe I should just adjust the time when I stop the timer?

**EDIT 3**
It seems like 15 ms works most of the times. But something makes ut unreliable, I think the best way is to just adjust the time.

Comment: 15 milliseconds is a *really really* short interval... Are you sure you want it that short?

Comment: Hehe I know it's short but it makes it nice cause you can really see how it is "fast forwarding". I thought like this 1000/60 = 16.666. But when I had that as the interval it was to fast so I went with 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'm going to answer this myself. I don't think I was clear enough. When I start the timer a timeout starts at the same time, that after one second stops the timer. This is where it goes wrong, the timer doesn't always show 01:00 when it stops.

So, the final solution is the set the seconds to 00 every time it stops, and because it all happens so fast, you wont notice.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $('.clock').html(rMin.slice(-2) + ':00');
}, 1000);
```

Check my updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tbleckert/pF4gs/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should be doing is storing your interval in a variable so that you can clear it, and start it again with a different delay.

```
var delay = 1000; // JavaScript uses milliseconds, so 1000 = 1 second
var theTimer  = '';

function startTimer(){
  theTimer = setInterval(function () {
     // Do awesome stuff here
  }, delay);
}

startTimer();
```

Now when you want to change the interval, or fast forward the timer, all you have to do is clear the current `setInterval` and define it again -

```
clearInterval(theTimer); // stop and clear the current timer
delay = 500; // Crank it up to twice the speed! 0.5 seconds!
startTimer(); // start a new setInterval();
```

### [Here is a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MVqvM/4/)

Comment: Yes of course. I have the interval stored and I have different functions for stop and start and fast forward. Your code will only make it twice as fast. I want my timer to go from 0 to 60 in one second. Also I want to display most of the seconds. Like the hockey clock the last minute if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myTimer(){
    this.startTime=0;
    this.intervalID=0;
    this.timePassed=0;
    this.multiplier=1;
    this.outputElement=null;
    this.start=function(){
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
        this.timePassed=0;
        this.outputElement=document.getElementById("output");
        this.startTime=new Date();
        var me = this;
        this.intervalID=setInterval(function(){
            me.update(me);
        },100);
    }
    this.toTwoDigit=function(num){
        if(num<10){
            return "0"+num;
        }
        return new String(num);
    }
    this.toThreeDigit=function(num){
        if(num<10){
            return "00"+num;
        }
        if(num<100){
            return "0"+num;
        }
        return new String(num);
    }
    this.update=function(me){
        me.timePassed=me.timePassed+(100*me.multiplier);
        var seconds=Math.floor(me.timePassed/1000);
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds/3600);
        var minutes = seconds-(hours*3600);
        seconds = seconds%60;
        minutes=Math.floor(minutes/60);
        me.outputElement.innerHTML= me.toTwoDigit(hours)+":"
            +me.toTwoDigit(minutes)+":"
            +me.toTwoDigit(seconds)
            +":"+me.toThreeDigit(Math.floor(me.timePassed%1000));
    }
    this.speedup=function(){
        this.multiplier=this.multiplier*2;
    }
    this.slowDown=function(){
        this.multiplier=this.multiplier/2;
    }
    this.stop=function(){
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
        this.update(this);
    }
}
var t = new myTimer();
</script>
</head>
<body onload="t.start();">
<input type="button" value="speed up" onclick="t.speedup()"></input>
<input type="button" value="slow down" onclick="t.slowDown()"></input>
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="t.stop()"></input>
<input type="button" value="restart" onclick="t.start()"></input>
<input type="button" value="(re)start times 60" onclick="t.multiplier=60;t.start()"></input>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say: "That works sometimes and sometimes not. Sometimes it stops att 01:02 instead of 01:00" but where in your code do you stop the timer? I updated my answer with the timercode showing how to implement it changing the add time value. If you need to raise an even when one minute has passed then I can implement it in there as well.